# Placement new and destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, placement-new

I have simple struct that has fixed size and contains build-in types. I create memory pool by allocating chunk of memory and I split this memory to blocks of size of my struct. Then it uses placement new to call constructor on particular memory block to initialize some members with default values. Then I would like to release whole memory chunk by calling delete[] operator. Can I safely skip explicit destructor call for each object initialized with placement new? I don't locate any resources inside constructor or inside constructors of other member fields of that class. I want just release whole memory chunk.

Comment: Please show your code instead of explaining it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you are doing, but generally, you can skip running the destructor if and only if the object is trivially destructible.

Comment: @BaummitAugen which in this case, the optimizer will do it anyway, so one should not really think about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip a call to destructor if it is *trivial*:

> [A trivial destructor is a destructor that performs no action. Objects with trivial destructors don't require a delete-expression and may be disposed of by simply deallocating their storage.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

You can tell if the type is trivially destructible using [`std::is_trivially_destructible<Type>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) expression. If you compile with optimization on, most optimizers will figure this out for you, so there will be no performance hit for writing a loop that calls trivial destructors for all objects in the block.

Comment: Not only can `std::is_trivially_destructible<>` be used to determine if it's fine. You REALLY should be using it in a `static_assert()` to ensure someone doesn't add a `string` to the struct in 6 months, or something silly like that.

Comment: What if struct or any member of it has explicitly defined destructor but with empty body?

Comment: @user7242858 Any explicitly provided destructor is *not* considered trivial, even if its body is empty.